# How to round between 2 date?

Tags: php

my problem is the result is 1 year, i need it round to be 2 year

```
$dx = new DateTime('2019-03-11'); $dy = new DateTime('2018-03-09');
$diff =$dy->diff($dx); 
echo ceil($diff->y);
```

Comment: So round the result, what's the problem?

Comment: the result 1 i need to be 2,

Comment: Your question is unclear. Write what is your expected result and what is current result. "result 1 i need to be 2" brings no value to that question.

Comment: @mate00 it's two days past one year so that means it should round up to two years

Comment: Then wy not simply return `2` instead? What about writing some test cases to cover the different input and output options and thenn fix the code accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
$dx = new DateTime('2019-03-11'); 
$dy = new DateTime('2018-03-09');
$diff =$dy->diff($dx); 

if(($diff->m > 0) || ($diff->d > 0)){
 echo ceil($diff->y) +1;
}else{
 echo ceil($diff->y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the diff a float of year and days then ceil it.

```
$dx = new DateTime('2019-03-11'); 
$dy = new DateTime('2018-03-09');
$diff =$dy->diff($dx); 
echo ceil($diff->y + $diff->d/1000);
```

https://3v4l.org/Sb5JE

Made a little mistake. It has to be divided by 1000 since there is 365 days in a year. Who knew?...

Comment: As a remark - there can be 23 hours for example in diff and 0 days.

Comment: That is a valid point. There could also be 1 second. I'll leave it as it is and let OP clarify his/her needs

Answer (score 0):

You could check the number of days that are between the dates, if it is bigger than 365 then ceil it, else return something else, in my case an string with "Less than one year":

```
$dx = new DateTime('2019-03-11'); $dy = new DateTime('2018-03-09');
$diff = $dy->diff($dx)->format("%a"); // number of days
$diffDivided = (int)$diff / 365 ;
return $diffDivided > 1 ? ceil($diffDivided) : 'Less than one year' ;
```

Comment: Nitpicking but, leap years?